# Enrichment analysis of DMPs | new Ilumina EPIC V2 900K

Tags: methylation, go-enrichment, epigenetics

Im analyzing methylation data from the new illumina's EPIC V2 array (900K).

I would like to perform enrichment analysis on DMPs. In the past, I have always used missMethyl but since there are a lot of differences between EPIC V1 and EPIC V2 arrays I'm unsure if missMethyl can be used (Im afraid results might be biased)

Does anyone know any enrichment tool already available for the EPIC V2 array or alternatives to missMethyl?

Thanks